# Outlook Addin ActiveExplorer and inspector CurrentItem with Attachments

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Need another view becouse im lost.

In outlook there are two ways to send an email, a new window for New Email or from a Message preview. I need a function that checks both sending options so that the user does not forget to attach the attachment.

I found this fantastic code here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54084998/3681759

The problem is that the function always says that no attachment is attached.

```
private void Btn_Check_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Inspector inspector = application.ActiveInspector();

        if (application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1] is MailItem explorerMailItem)
        {
            if (explorerMailItem.Attachments.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Attachments isnt here");
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                AddItemsForm f2 = new AddItemsForm();
                f2.ShowDialog();
                this.Hide();
            }

        } else if (inspector.CurrentItem is MailItem inspectorMailItem)
            {
                if (inspectorMailItem.Attachments.Count == 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Attachment isnt here");
                    this.Hide();
                } else {
                    AddItemsForm f2 = new AddItemsForm();
                    f2.ShowDialog();
                    this.Hide();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, use `Application.ActiveWindow` and cast it as `Inspector` or `Explorer` to see which window is actually active.

Secondly, in case of `Explorer`, do not use `Explorer.Selection`, use `Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse` (returns null or the new item being composed inline).